# How to make the hamburger menu fit entire page in react jsx

Tags: reactjs, react-native, web

I am very new to react jsx, and I am using tailwind which is very good. I am also learning it as I go. So in my navigation I was able to make the hamburger menu show but I don't like how they appear. I am trying to ensure I get the entire page filled with white page see image second image below.

This is what I was able to achieve, and I don't think it looks clean

[image]

What I want to achieve,or something similar, the white fill the entire website and show the options

[image]

My question now is, with my code; how can I achieve this? this is my navigation jsx, I will appreciate any help. I am the only team member and no lead dev to help.

```
import logo from "./favicon.png";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";
import { useInView } from "react-intersection-observer";
import MenuDropdown from "./MenuDropdown";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function Navigation() {
  const [ref, inView] = useInView({ triggerOnce: false });
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  const [navVisible, setNaVisible] = useState(false);

  const megaMenu = document.getElementById("mega-menu");

  return (
    <motion.nav
      className="flex items-center justify-between flex-wrap px-6 lg:px-12 py-8 max-w-full mx-auto"
      ref={ref}
      initial={{ y: -10, opacity: 0 }}
      animate={inView ? { y: 0, opacity: 1 } : {}}
      exit={{ y: -10, opacity: 0 }}
      transition={{ duration: 0.5 }}
    >
      <a
        href="/"
        className="flex flex-row items-center flex-shrink-0 text-white mr-6 lg:pr-16 space-x-2"
      >
        <img src={logo} className="w-8 h-8" alt="Logo"></img>
        <h2 className="font-bold text-2xl tracking-tight">Jibu Labs</h2>
      </a>

      <div id="menu" className="block lg:hidden">
        <button
          className="flex items-center px-3 py-2 border rounded text-slate-200 border-slate-400 duration-100 hover:text-white hover:border-white"
          onClick={() => setNaVisible(!navVisible)}
        >
          <svg
            className="fill-current h-3 w-3"
            viewBox="0 0 20 20"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          >
            <title>Menu</title>
            <path d="M0 3h20v2H0V3zm0 6h20v2H0V9zm0 6h20v2H0v-2z" />
          </svg>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div
        className={`
        ${
          navVisible
            ? "w-full block flex-grow g:flex lg:items-center lg:w-auto"
            : "lg:flex flex-none w-6/12 hidden lg:content-right"
        }`}
      >
        <div
          className={`
        ${
          navVisible
            ? "lg:flex-grow flex flex-col  text-sm"
            : "lg:flex-grow flex flex-rows space-x-12 text-sm "
        }`}
        >
          <div
            className={`${
              !navVisible
                ? "flex flex-rows items-center space-x-2 text-white"
                : "flex flex-rows items-center space-x-2 text-white justify-end pr-12"
            }`}
          >
            <span className="ring-1 p-0.5 ring-white rounded-full"></span>
            <Link
              to="projects"
              className={`${
                !navVisible
                  ? "block mt-4 lg:inline-block lg:mt-0 text-white mr-4"
                  : "block mt-4 lg:inline-block lg:mt-0 text-white mr-4 justify-end "
              }`}
            >
              Work
            </Link>
          </div>

          {!navVisible ? (
            <div
              id="mega-menu"
              className={`flex items-center space-x-2 flex-rows text-white  
          
            `}
              onClick={() => setIsOpen((prev) => !prev)}
            >
              <span className="ring-1 p-0.5 ring-white rounded-full"></span>
              <div className="block mt-4 lg:inline-block lg:mt-0 mr-4 cursor-pointer">
                Effeciencies
              </div>
              <svg
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                fill="none"
                viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                strokeWidth={1}
                stroke="currentColor"
                className="w-4 h-4"
              >
                <path
                  strokeLinecap="round"
                  strokeLinejoin="round"
                  d="M19.5 8.25l-7.5 7.5-7.5-7.5"
                />
              </svg>
            </div>
          ) : (
            <div
              className={`${
                !navVisible
                  ? "flex flex-rows items-center space-x-2 text-white"
                  : "flex flex-rows items-center space-x-2 text-white justify-end"
              }`}
            >
              <span className="ring-1 p-0.5 ring-white rounded-full"></span>
              <Link
                to="strategy"
                className="block mt-4 lg:inline-block lg:mt-0 text-white mr-4 justify-end pr-1"
              >
                Effeciencies
              </Link>
            </div>
          )}

          <div
            className={`${
              !navVisible
                ? "flex flex-rows items-center space-x-2 text-white"
                : "flex flex-rows items-center space-x-2 text-white justify-end pr-10"
            }`}
          >
            <span className="ring-1 p-0.5 ring-white rounded-full"></span>
            <a
              href="about"
              className="block mt-4 lg:inline-block lg:mt-0 text-white mr-4"
            >
              About
            </a>
          </div>
          <div
            className={`${
              !navVisible
                ? "flex flex-rows items-center space-x-2 text-white"
                : "flex flex-rows items-center space-x-2 text-white justify-end pr-7"
            }`}
          >
            <span className="ring-1 p-0.5 ring-white rounded-full"></span>
            <a
              href="careers"
              className="block mt-4 lg:inline-block lg:mt-0 text-white mr-7"
            >
              Careers
            </a>
          </div>
          <div
            className={`${
              !navVisible
                ? "flex flex-rows items-center space-x-2 text-white"
                : "flex flex-rows items-center space-x-2 text-white justify-end pr-7"
            }`}
          >
            <span className="ring-1 p-0.5 ring-white rounded-full"></span>
            <a
              href="contact"
              className="block mt-4 lg:inline-block lg:mt-0 text-white mr-4"
            >
              Contact
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <MenuDropdown isOpen={isOpen} setIsOpen={setIsOpen} />
      
    </motion.nav>
  );
}
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, it is the MenuDropdown component that needs to fill the page, correct? Also, do you need to the menu to occupy only the entire height of the viewport or is it the entire viewport, meaning, height and width?

Comment: Alright, my bad, it seems like motion.nav is the component that is supposed to fill the space. In any case, please let us know which one is the component that needs to fill the space and also do share the CSS file of that particular component.

Comment: A sandbox is your best bet for faster solution, If you share one I can help fix it.

Comment: @Suraya provided example is just copy pasted code, its not opening anything, I tried opening to a extent but not much happening due to animations, if you can share the working example I can try to help, https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-wu-75sxd8?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

To fill the entire page with white or another background color, you need an outer div that sets the height to 100vh and width to 100vw. The 100vh means set the height to 100% of the viewport height of the web browser screen and 100vw means 100% of the viewport width.

```
return (
   <div style={{height: "100vh", width: "100vw", maxWidth: "100%", background: "white"}}>
    <motion.nav
      className="flex items-center justify-between flex-wrap px-6 lg:px-12 
   ...
    </motion.nav>
  </div>
```

The setting of maxWidth to 100% is to prevent the display of a scroll bar if the body tag has padding or there are some other outer components taking up space.

The above makes the motion.nav component take up the full page. You might want to move the full page div higher up to the JSX that makes use of the component.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Am lost abit, I tried but it just filled the top part. I am also new to this as I do Android. If there a way you can demo on the code I shared.

Comment: Hi Suraya, I tried setting the code up in a [React with Tailwind Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/tailwind-css-and-react-kgb5h) but there are some other files in your project such as ./MenuDropdown.js that are required. I suggest you have a go setting the project up in a Sandbox and then you can save it and post a link to it.

Comment: Instead of placing the nav within a div and assigning it a height of 100vh, did you try assigning a height of 100vh to the nav itself?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the CSS of the `motion.nav` to:

```
`motion.nav{
  margin: 0;
  width:100%;
  max-width: 100vw;
  min-height:100vh;
  padding: 20px;
}`
```

This solution should work providing that there parent of `motion.nav` (if any) does not have padding.

The code above should ensure that there is no margins stopping the container from reaching the entire page, set the width to 100% of the users viewport (and ensure it does not go over) as well as set the minimum height of your menu to 100% of the users viewport. We set the minimum height to allow for the menu to grow should you want more menu items and finally padding to make the menu a tad neat.

I hope this solution works for you! Have a great day.

**EDIT**

You should place the above CSS code into a file called `[YourFileName].css` and then import that file into your React page.

Please see an example of importing the stylesheet into react below:

```
 //Imported CSS file below
 import "./style.css"; 
 export default function CoolFunc(){
 return (
         <>
              <div className="ElemToStyle">
              </div>
         </>
     );
 }`
```

Comment: That on the code won't compile how do I add it?

Comment: You will need to add the code to your stylesheet, eg `style.css` and then import that stylesheet into your project. Apologies for not explaining that previously

Here is an example of the code to import the style sheet:

`import React from "react";
import "./style.css";

export default function CoolFunc(){
    return (
        <>
             <div className="ElemToStyle">
             </div>
        </>
    );
}`

Here is an example of the style.css file:
`motion.nav{
  margin: 0;
  width:100%;
  max-width: 100vw;
  min-height:100vh;
  padding: 20px;
}`